# Salesforce Invoice Standard Object New Button is missing

Tags: lightning, standard-objects, sales, classic

I have noticed that Salesforce does not provide the option to create a new record on its Invoice Standard object, in classic and lightning both.
I am using the System Administrator profile.
Using salesforce developer edition.
Why it does not allow to do so and how to create a new record using the Invoice Standard object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you check Invoice--> Search Layouts --> List View --> Edit, Checkbox for New [New]?

Comment: Search layout doesn’t list view option there.

Comment: I am assuming you referring to the Invoice object within Salesforce Order Management?

Also have you made sure you access the appropriate License and and Permission Sets associated with Salesforce Order Management which might be possibly restricting access. Another potential reason could be the CRUD access provided by the Profile.

Check the following article on - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.om_view_an_invoice.htm&type=5